# Launching composed task runner with secured Spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I've enabled basic security in SCDF and trying to invoke CTR via rest endpoint. My question is how can I pass credentials to CTR to be used to access SCDF? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is descibed [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1972#issuecomment-372813260)

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed in [Gitter](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow?at=5aa95144e4d1c63604fce752). We are researching OAuth possibilities between SCDF <-> CTR right now.